# Finding homeomorphism between a triangle and a quarter circle

Tags: general-topology

So I have two spaces:

$$X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x>1,\,y>1,\,y<-x+3\}$$

$$Y=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2<1,\,y<-1,\,x<-1\}$$

I need to find a homeomorphism between the triangle $X$ and quarter of a circle $Y$.

I think I should somehow get edges into edges, but I don't know the rest.

I think I should get a function that is a linear function, but with little tweaks, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that we can transform these spaces each to more sensible ones by linear automorphisms - that is, as you describe, they are a triangle and a quarter of a circle, so we may as well may them look similar:
$$X'=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x,y>0,\,x+y<1\}$$
$$Y'=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x,y>0,\,x^2+y^2<1\}$$
That is, you can easily find homeomorphisms $X\rightarrow X'$ and $Y\rightarrow Y'$. However, there's an obvious homeomorphism $Y'\rightarrow X'$ from the definition: Just take $(x,y)$ to $(x^2,y^2)$.

You can also follow your intution for a "modified" linear thing to scale ray out of the origin appropriately, which gives
$$(x,y)\mapsto \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot(x,y)$$
where each ray of the triangle is lengthened by the appropriate factor to reach the edge of the circle. An inverse for this is reasonably easy to find as well.